# Setup Commerce Server

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-server

I am following the [Sitecore Commerce Deployment Guide](http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreCommerce/DeploymentGuide/en-us/index.html#Concepts/c_SC_SetUpCommerceServerSite.html).

No errors until the New-CSWebService command on power shell.

[image]

The message is quite straight forward:

> New-CSWebService :The specified directory service attribute or value
>   does not exist

---

But how can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running Powershell as admin? Also, what Windows Operating syustem you are installing on? Windows 10 or something else? Checkout this link and check with your System admin if you need to - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2672326/fix-the-specified-directory-service-attribute-or-value-does-not-exist

Comment: Windows 10. Thank you. I was also following the pages on your blog. I think some step is not completing properly. I will reinstall in on a clean machine.

Comment: Looks like your Administrator user has different name instead of 'Administrator'